# implementing webview to use vimeo embed link

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview

I am having issue in embedding my vimeo video through webview using the embed code below.

```
> <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/{some-video-id}" width="640"
> height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen"
> allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

**can anyone please help me how do I use above code with *flutter* webview widget?**

here is my code snippet

```
Container(
        child: 
        WebView(
        initialUrl: new Uri.dataFromString("<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/{some-video-id}" width="640"
          height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen"
          allowfullscreen></iframe> </p>", 
          mimeType: "text/html", encoding: utf8).toString(),
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
        _controller.complete(webViewController);
        },
       ),
      ),
    );
```

this isn't working at all.
I'm trying to get it working for a long time, if anyone could help me with this, it would mean world to me!

**THANK YOU** FOR YOUR TIME!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a quick glance, I can see that your string isn't properly delineated ... the initial string should be encased inside **single-quotes** so you can write the HTML attributes with **double-quotes** as such:

```
'<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/{some-video-id}" width="640" height="360"
 frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen></iframe> </p>'
```

Comment: OMG it worked! how stupid I am to forget to put the string inside single quotes. Thanks man, you saved my day.